# Key needs a lot of force to type (Samsung NC10)

Tags: keyboard

I just got a **Samsung NC10**.

It was working OK but now my "P "key hardly registers unless I press it real hard.

I took the key button off as well as the "O" key to compare and I noticed that the "P" has a clip/bracket (I don't know the best way to describe this) slightly raised more than the "O" key.

However there is no way to press it down or clip on to anything.

I know this post is vague but any ideas?

Comment: Since you got poked by "Community", what about the photos ?

Answer (score 0):

How long ago did you buy it? This sounds like something that should be replaced in warranty.

Comment: I got it off Ebay so no receipt :( It was working fine for the last week though

Comment: Ok, then I think we'll need the pictures to be able to say anything more.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that perhaps some food (or other) particles got under the key and jammed it up?  It's surprising how often I run across this problem only to find cracker crumbs (or similar) all jammed up under the keys...